# No valid proxy can be found to do this operation error while republishing the Content Type in Content Type Hub

Tags: content-type, publishing, content-type-hub

I am getting this error "`No valid proxy can be found to do this operation.`" when I republished the content types from my **Content Type Hub.**

Usually it successfully republishes the updates from my content type and I was able to ran the timer jobs without any hindrances.Suddenly this CTH starts behaving strangely. Still not able to understand why it failed. 
Any Ideas as to why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things to check:

- Make sure that MMS proxy associated with the web app.( Central admin > Application management > web app and from ribbon select service connection)
- Also check if MMS services is running on at least one server in the farm.( Central admin > Managed Services on server.)
- Also browse the MMS from central admin and see if it working fine.
- Lastly IIS reset on the server where MMS is running.
- also check this one: http://sharepoint-for-real.blogspot.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-content-type-publishing.html

Comment: Thanks Waqas for the reply.I will test the steps and revert.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the content type syndication hub Url in the managed metadata properties is set correctly.

Check that the managed metadata service application group owner and admins also have at least read permission on the content type syndication hub site collection.

Browse to the Content type syndication hub webapp and make sure it is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was simply to change the Content Type Hub URL since we moved from HTTP to HTTPS only.

SharePoint 2013 Management Shell:

```
$serviceName = "Managed Metadata Service"
$hubUrl = "https://subdomain.mycompany.com/cthub"
Set-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Identity $serviceName -HubURI $hubUrl
```